# How to edit data from database in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following form used for creating banner points(button details) in my app for creating banners.

HTML

```
<div class='container'>

    <div class='left-panel'>
      <form *ngIf='editMode === false'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]="title" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Price" [(ngModel)]="price" />
         <inputtype="text" placeholder="Link" [(ngModel)]="link" />
        <button (click)="saveItem()">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class='right-panel'>
      // The banner goes here 
           <div
                  class="point-box"
                  (click)="onPointClicked(+item.button_id, item)"
                  [style.left.%]="item.x"
                  [style.top.%]="item.y"
                  [attr.data-id]="item.button_id"
                  [id]="'button-' + item.button_id"
                  (mouseenter)="onButtonHover(item.button_id)"
                >
                </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

TS.

```
addItem (){

    const tooltip = {
      toltipId: this.dataId,
      title: this.title,
      price: this.price,
      link: this.link,
      tooltipThumbnailUrl: this.tooltipThumbnailUrl,
      right: this.rightValue,
      left: this.leftValue,
      top: this.topValue,
    };

    const item = {
      pointId: this.dataId,
      x: this.xPercentage,
      y: this.yPercentage,
      tooltip: tooltip,
    };

    this.bannerData.points.push(item);// data to database will be used in post method
    this.dataService.addItem(item);
}
```

This works as expected, the creation of the button  works well

When I click the edit button it opens the page editor, On the page editor's left side I have the form above, and on the right side, I have the banner with 2 points(buttons).

Now I want the user to click one of the buttons to show the form with input values related to the clicked button.

I tried this

```
    <ng-container *ngIf='editMode === true'>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of bannerData.points">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="pointClickedId ===  item.pointClickedId ">
                <form >

                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]="item.tooltip?.title" />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Price" [(ngModel)]=".item.tooltip?price" />
                <inputtype="text" placeholder="Link" [(ngModel)]="item.tooltip?.link" />
                <button (click)="saveItem()">Save</button>
                
                 </form>
                 </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

When I save by pushing them to service and this.bannerData.points, the item elements of title, price, and link are empty.

I am struggling to make this work, can anyone help me out with this?